# markers disappear when resizing the canvas?

Tags: api, mobile, maps, marker

I'm trying to develop a responsive website and even if my Google map displays fine, no marker appear on it if I decrease the size of the window (or if I use a mobile device)…
Here is an example page: http://www.parisdigest.com/test-mobile.htm (the marker should appear on Paris).
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. My responsive CSS contained some code to add a max-width to some elements, including "div". I just added  div#map_canvas,#map_canvas div{max-width: none} and solved this issue.